# Unicode character in string literal issue

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, visual-studio-2013, string-literals

I have Unicode character in string literal in my unit test. When I copy and paste it as "å" it is represented as "a" at runtime. When I try to compare this symbol with it's Unicode code "\u00e5" test fails.

```
Assert.AreEqual("å", "\u00e5");
```

I have checked that file in Visual Studio is saved as Unicode - Codepage 65001.

I have tried to search internet but couldn't find any explanation why this happens.

Also I have tried to create same test in new solution and test passes. So it might be something wrong with my settings in current solution. Can anyone help me with this issue?

**EDIT:** I have changed project type from Class library to Console application and back and test started to pass. I have no idea what was it. I'm using NCrunch as test runner so maybe it was an issue related to it. Should I remove this question?

Comment: What type of application is this?

Comment: `bool b = "å" == "\u00e5";` returns *true*

Comment: @L.B He stated it worked in a new test solution, so what configuration could make it NOT work?  make your bool check return false and report what change did that L.B.

Comment: @Zach, it's class library. Project for Unit tests.

Comment: To clarify, your current solution had a test where this failed and the new solution had a test (same project type) and it failed, correct?

Comment: Yes, test fails in old solution and passes in new one.

Comment: In the old and new solution can you please compare the cultureinfo? `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It passes for Console application project and fails for Class library.

Comment: That's really weird. I've changes project type back to Class library and test passes now.

Comment: Well that's good. In these types of cases I would always look at the currentculture.

Comment: @Zach, thanks a lot, without your hint I don't know what would I do. By the way I set current culture to "da" to test this particular string.

Comment: Clean your solution and switch to release and make sure it still works.

Comment: Yes, it passes in all cases now. I suppose the file was initially saved in different encoding and NCrunch has cached it in old encoding. After I have changed project type NCrunch started to use new Unicode encoding.

Comment: Just to throw another possibility in, it might be that it was initially the sequence `a` + `U+030A COMBINING RING ABOVE` which if you outputted only one char, explains why it was "a" at runtime. At some point, it might have gotten normalized to the composed version `U+00E5 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE`.